# Why when I submitted two commandbuffer, just one commandbuffer executed?

Tags: c++, vulkan

```
void VEngine::initVulkan() {
    createInstance();
    setupDebugCallback();
    createSurface();
    pickPhysicalDevice();
    createLogicalDevice();
    createSemaphores();
    createSwapChain();
    createImageViews();
    createCommandPool();
    createRenderPass();
    createFramebuffers();
    CreateShadowRenderPass();
    CreateShadowFrameBuffer();


    createDescriptorSetLayout();
    createGraphicsPipeline();
    SetTextureInfo();
    createVertexBuffer();
    createIndexBuffer();
    createUniformBuffer();
    createDescriptorPool();
    createDescriptorSet();
    CreateCommandBuffers();


    CreateShadowLayout();
    CreateShadowPipeline();
    CreateShadowVertexBuffer();
    CreateShadowIndexBuffer();
    CreateShadowUniformBuffer();
    CreateShadowDescriptorPool();
    CreateShadowDescriptorSet();
    CreateShadowCommandBuffer();

}

void VEngine::CreateCommandBuffers()
{

    commandBuffers.resize(swapChainFramebuffers.size());

    VkCommandBufferAllocateInfo allocInfo = {};
    allocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    allocInfo.commandPool = commandPool;
    allocInfo.level = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY;
    allocInfo.commandBufferCount = (uint32_t)commandBuffers.size();

    if (vkAllocateCommandBuffers(device, &allocInfo, commandBuffers.data()) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to allocate command buffers!");
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < commandBuffers.size(); i++) {
        VkCommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfo = {};
        beginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
        beginInfo.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_SIMULTANEOUS_USE_BIT;

        vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[i], &beginInfo);

        VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassInfo = {};
        renderPassInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
        renderPassInfo.renderPass = renderPass;
        renderPassInfo.framebuffer = swapChainFramebuffers[i];
        renderPassInfo.renderArea.offset = { 0, 0 };
        renderPassInfo.renderArea.extent = swapChainExtent;

        std::array<VkClearValue, 2> clearValues = {};
        clearValues[0].color = { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f };
        clearValues[1].depthStencil = { 1.0f, 0 };

        renderPassInfo.clearValueCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(clearValues.size());
        renderPassInfo.pClearValues = clearValues.data();

        vkCmdBeginRenderPass(commandBuffers[i], &renderPassInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);

        vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, graphicsPipeline);

        VkBuffer vertexBuffers[] = { vertexBuffer };
        VkDeviceSize offsets[] = { 0 };
        vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffers[i], 0, 1, vertexBuffers, offsets);

        vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(commandBuffers[i], indexBuffer, 0, VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32);

        vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipelineLayout, 0, 1, &descriptorSet, 0, nullptr);

        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);

        vkCmdPushConstants(commandBuffers[i], pipelineLayout, VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT, 0, sizeof(ConstantMatrixModel), &model);

        vkCmdDrawIndexed(commandBuffers[i], static_cast<uint32_t>(indices.size()), 1, 0, 0, 0);

        vkCmdEndRenderPass(commandBuffers[i]);

        if (vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[i]) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to record command buffer!");
        }
    }
}


void VEngine::drawFrame() {
    uint32_t imageIndex;
    VkResult result = vkAcquireNextImageKHR(device, swapChain, std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max(), imageAvailableSemaphore, VK_NULL_HANDLE, &imageIndex);

   /* if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR) {
        recreateSwapChain();
        return;
    }
    else if (result != VK_SUCCESS && result != VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to acquire swap chain image!");
    }*/

    VkSubmitInfo shadowSubmitInfo = {};
    shadowSubmitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;

    VkPipelineStageFlags shadowWaitStages[] = { VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT };
    shadowSubmitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
    shadowSubmitInfo.pWaitSemaphores = &imageAvailableSemaphore;
    shadowSubmitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask = shadowWaitStages;

    shadowSubmitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
    shadowSubmitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = &shadowSemaphore;

    shadowSubmitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &shadowCommandbuffer;

    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkQueueSubmit(presentQueue, 1, &shadowSubmitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE));

    VkSubmitInfo submitInfo = {};
    submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;

    VkPipelineStageFlags waitStages[] = { VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT };
    submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores = &shadowSemaphore;
    submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask = waitStages;

    submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffers[imageIndex];

    submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = &renderFinishedSemaphore;

    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkQueueSubmit(presentQueue, 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE)); 

    VkPresentInfoKHR presentInfo = {};
    presentInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR;

    presentInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
    presentInfo.pWaitSemaphores = &renderFinishedSemaphore;

    VkSwapchainKHR swapChains[] = { swapChain };
    presentInfo.swapchainCount = 1;
    presentInfo.pSwapchains = swapChains;

    presentInfo.pImageIndices = &imageIndex;

    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkQueuePresentKHR(presentQueue, &presentInfo));

    //if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR || result == VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR) {
    //    recreateSwapChain();
    //}
    //else if (result != VK_SUCCESS) {
    //    throw std::runtime_error("failed to present swap chain image!");
    //}

    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkQueueWaitIdle(presentQueue));
}


void VEngine::CreateShadowFrameBuffer()
{
    // For shadow mapping we only need a depth attachment
    VkImageCreateInfo image = {};
    image.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    image.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
    image.extent.width = shadow_width;
    image.extent.height = shadow_height;
    image.extent.depth = 1;
    image.mipLevels = 1;
    image.arrayLayers = 1;
    image.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    image.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
    image.format = DEPTH_FORMAT;                                                                // Depth stencil attachment
    image.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT;     // We will sample directly from the depth attachment for the shadow mapping
    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateImage(device, &image, nullptr, &shadowImage));

    VkMemoryAllocateInfo memAlloc = {};
    VkMemoryRequirements memReqs = {};

    memAlloc.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    vkGetImageMemoryRequirements(device, shadowImage, &memReqs);
    memAlloc.allocationSize = memReqs.size;

    memAlloc.memoryTypeIndex = findMemoryType(memReqs.memoryTypeBits, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT);
    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkAllocateMemory(device, &memAlloc, nullptr, &shadowImageMemory));

    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkBindImageMemory(device, shadowImage, shadowImageMemory, 0));

    VkImageViewCreateInfo depthStencilView = {};
    depthStencilView.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
    depthStencilView.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
    depthStencilView.format = DEPTH_FORMAT;
    depthStencilView.subresourceRange = {};
    depthStencilView.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_DEPTH_BIT;
    depthStencilView.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
    depthStencilView.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
    depthStencilView.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    depthStencilView.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
    depthStencilView.image = shadowImage;
    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateImageView(device, &depthStencilView, nullptr, &shadowImageView));

    // Create sampler to sample from to depth attachment 
    // Used to sample in the fragment shader for shadowed rendering
    VkSamplerCreateInfo sampler = {};
    sampler.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SAMPLER_CREATE_INFO;
    sampler.magFilter = SHADOWMAP_FILTER;
    sampler.minFilter = SHADOWMAP_FILTER;
    sampler.mipmapMode = VK_SAMPLER_MIPMAP_MODE_LINEAR;
    sampler.addressModeU = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;
    sampler.addressModeV = sampler.addressModeU;
    sampler.addressModeW = sampler.addressModeU;
    sampler.mipLodBias = 0.0f;
    sampler.maxAnisotropy = 0;
    sampler.minLod = 0.0f;
    sampler.maxLod = 1.0f;
    sampler.borderColor = VK_BORDER_COLOR_FLOAT_OPAQUE_WHITE;
    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateSampler(device, &sampler, nullptr, &shadowImageSampler));

    // Create frame buffer
    VkFramebufferCreateInfo fbufCreateInfo = {};
    fbufCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FRAMEBUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
    fbufCreateInfo.renderPass = shadowRenderPass;
    fbufCreateInfo.attachmentCount = 1;
    fbufCreateInfo.pAttachments = &shadowImageView;
    fbufCreateInfo.width = shadow_width;
    fbufCreateInfo.height = shadow_height;
    fbufCreateInfo.layers = 1;

    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateFramebuffer(device, &fbufCreateInfo, nullptr, &shadowFramebuffers));


}

void VEngine::CreateShadowRenderPass()
{
    VkAttachmentDescription attachmentDescription = {};
    attachmentDescription.format = DEPTH_FORMAT;
    attachmentDescription.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    attachmentDescription.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;                         // Clear depth at beginning of the render pass
    attachmentDescription.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;                       // We will read from depth, so it's important to store the depth attachment results
    attachmentDescription.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachmentDescription.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachmentDescription.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;                    // We don't care about initial layout of the attachment
    attachmentDescription.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;// Attachment will be transitioned to shader read at render pass end

    VkAttachmentReference depthReference = {};
    depthReference.attachment = 0;
    depthReference.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;           // Attachment will be used as depth/stencil during render pass

    VkSubpassDescription subpass = {};
    subpass.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
    subpass.colorAttachmentCount = 0;                                                   // No color attachments
    subpass.pDepthStencilAttachment = &depthReference;                                  // Reference to our depth attachment
                                                                                        // Use subpass dependencies for layout transitions
    std::array<VkSubpassDependency, 2> dependencies;

    dependencies[0].srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
    dependencies[0].dstSubpass = 0;
    dependencies[0].srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT;
    dependencies[0].dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_LATE_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT;
    dependencies[0].srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT;
    dependencies[0].dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
    dependencies[0].dependencyFlags = VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT;

    dependencies[1].srcSubpass = 0;
    dependencies[1].dstSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
    dependencies[1].srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_LATE_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT;
    dependencies[1].dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT;
    dependencies[1].srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
    dependencies[1].dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT;
    dependencies[1].dependencyFlags = VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT;

    VkRenderPassCreateInfo renderPassCreateInfo = {};
    renderPassCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
    renderPassCreateInfo.attachmentCount = 1;
    renderPassCreateInfo.pAttachments = &attachmentDescription;
    renderPassCreateInfo.subpassCount = 1;
    renderPassCreateInfo.pSubpasses = &subpass;
    renderPassCreateInfo.dependencyCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(dependencies.size());
    renderPassCreateInfo.pDependencies = dependencies.data();

    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateRenderPass(device, &renderPassCreateInfo, nullptr, &shadowRenderPass));
}

void VEngine::CreateShadowLayout()
{

    std::vector<VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding> setLayoutBindings;

    VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding ubo{
        0,
        VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER,
        1,
        VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT,
        nullptr
    };

    setLayoutBindings.push_back(ubo);

    VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo descriptorLayout = {};
    descriptorLayout.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
    descriptorLayout.bindingCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(setLayoutBindings.size());
    descriptorLayout.pBindings = setLayoutBindings.data();

    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout(device, &descriptorLayout, nullptr, &shadowDescriptorSetLayout));

    VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo pPipelineLayoutCreateInfo = {};
    pPipelineLayoutCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
    pPipelineLayoutCreateInfo.setLayoutCount = 1;
    pPipelineLayoutCreateInfo.pSetLayouts = &shadowDescriptorSetLayout;

    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreatePipelineLayout(device, &pPipelineLayoutCreateInfo, nullptr, &shadowPipelineLayout));

}

void VEngine::CreateShadowVertexBuffer()
{
    VkDeviceSize bufferSize = sizeof(shadowVertices[0]) * shadowVertices.size();

    VkBuffer stagingBuffer;
    VkDeviceMemory stagingBufferMemory;
    createBuffer(bufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, stagingBuffer, stagingBufferMemory);

    void* data;
    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkMapMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory, 0, bufferSize, 0, &data));
    memcpy(data, shadowVertices.data(), (size_t)bufferSize);
    vkUnmapMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory);

    createBuffer(bufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT, shadowVertexBuffer, shadowVertexBufferMemory);

    copyBuffer(stagingBuffer, shadowVertexBuffer, bufferSize);

    vkDestroyBuffer(device, stagingBuffer, nullptr);
    vkFreeMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory, nullptr);

}

void VEngine::CreateShadowIndexBuffer()
{
    VkDeviceSize bufferSize = sizeof(shadowIndices[0]) * shadowIndices.size();

    VkBuffer stagingBuffer;
    VkDeviceMemory stagingBufferMemory;
    createBuffer(bufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, stagingBuffer, stagingBufferMemory);

    void* data;
    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkMapMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory, 0, bufferSize, 0, &data));
    memcpy(data, shadowIndices.data(), (size_t)bufferSize);
    vkUnmapMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory);

    createBuffer(bufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_INDEX_BUFFER_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT, shadowIndexBuffer, shadowIndexBufferMemory);

    copyBuffer(stagingBuffer, shadowIndexBuffer, bufferSize);

    vkDestroyBuffer(device, stagingBuffer, nullptr);
    vkFreeMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory, nullptr);

}

void VEngine::CreateShadowUniformBuffer()
{
    createBuffer(sizeof(ShadowUBO), VK_BUFFER_USAGE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, shadowUniformBuffer, shadowUniformBufferMemory);

    UpdateShadowUniformBuffer();
}

void VEngine::CreateShadowDescriptorPool()
{
    std::array<VkDescriptorPoolSize, 1> poolSizes = {};
    poolSizes[0].type = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER;
    poolSizes[0].descriptorCount = 1;

    VkDescriptorPoolCreateInfo poolInfo = {};
    poolInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_POOL_CREATE_INFO;
    poolInfo.poolSizeCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(poolSizes.size());
    poolInfo.pPoolSizes = poolSizes.data();
    poolInfo.maxSets = 1;

    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateDescriptorPool(device, &poolInfo, nullptr, &shadowDescriptorPool));

}

void VEngine::CreateShadowDescriptorSet()
{
    VkDescriptorSetLayout layouts[] = { shadowDescriptorSetLayout };
    VkDescriptorSetAllocateInfo allocInfo = {};
    allocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    allocInfo.descriptorPool = shadowDescriptorPool;
    allocInfo.descriptorSetCount = 1;
    allocInfo.pSetLayouts = layouts;

    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkAllocateDescriptorSets(device, &allocInfo, &shadowDescriptorSet));

    VkDescriptorBufferInfo matrixBufferInfo = {};
    matrixBufferInfo.buffer = shadowUniformBuffer;
    matrixBufferInfo.offset = 0;
    matrixBufferInfo.range = sizeof(ShadowUBO);

    std::array<VkWriteDescriptorSet, 1> descriptorWrites = {};

    descriptorWrites[0].sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WRITE_DESCRIPTOR_SET;
    descriptorWrites[0].dstSet = shadowDescriptorSet;
    descriptorWrites[0].dstBinding = 0;
    descriptorWrites[0].dstArrayElement = 0;
    descriptorWrites[0].descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER;
    descriptorWrites[0].descriptorCount = 1;
    descriptorWrites[0].pBufferInfo = &matrixBufferInfo;


    vkUpdateDescriptorSets(device, static_cast<uint32_t>(descriptorWrites.size()), descriptorWrites.data(), 0, nullptr);
}

void VEngine::CreateShadowPipeline()
{
    auto vertShaderCode = readFile("D:/project/vulkan_engine/media/shaders/shadow/offscreen.vert.spv");
    auto fragShaderCode = readFile("D:/project/vulkan_engine/media/shaders/shadow/offscreen.frag.spv");

    VkShaderModule shadowVertShaderModule = createShaderModule(vertShaderCode);
    VkShaderModule shadowFragShaderModule = createShaderModule(fragShaderCode);

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo vertShaderStageInfo = {};
    vertShaderStageInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    vertShaderStageInfo.stage = VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT;
    vertShaderStageInfo.module = shadowVertShaderModule;
    vertShaderStageInfo.pName = "main";

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo fragShaderStageInfo = {};
    fragShaderStageInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    fragShaderStageInfo.stage = VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT;
    fragShaderStageInfo.module = shadowFragShaderModule;
    fragShaderStageInfo.pName = "main";

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo shaderStages[] = { vertShaderStageInfo, fragShaderStageInfo };

    VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo vertexInputInfo = {};
    vertexInputInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VERTEX_INPUT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;

    auto bindingDescription = ShadowVertex::getBindingDescription();
    auto attributeDescriptions = ShadowVertex::getAttributeDescriptions();

    vertexInputInfo.vertexBindingDescriptionCount = 1;
    vertexInputInfo.vertexAttributeDescriptionCount = 1;
    vertexInputInfo.pVertexBindingDescriptions = &bindingDescription;
    vertexInputInfo.pVertexAttributeDescriptions = attributeDescriptions.data();

    VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo inputAssembly = {};
    inputAssembly.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_INPUT_ASSEMBLY_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    inputAssembly.topology = VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST;
    inputAssembly.primitiveRestartEnable = VK_FALSE;

    VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo viewportState = {};
    viewportState.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VIEWPORT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    viewportState.viewportCount = 1;
    viewportState.scissorCount = 1;

    VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo rasterizer = {};
    rasterizer.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RASTERIZATION_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    rasterizer.depthClampEnable = VK_FALSE;
    rasterizer.rasterizerDiscardEnable = VK_FALSE;
    rasterizer.polygonMode = VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL;
    rasterizer.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    rasterizer.cullMode = VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT;
    rasterizer.frontFace = VK_FRONT_FACE_COUNTER_CLOCKWISE;
    rasterizer.depthBiasEnable = VK_TRUE;

    VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo multisampling = {};
    multisampling.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_MULTISAMPLE_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    multisampling.sampleShadingEnable = VK_FALSE;
    multisampling.rasterizationSamples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;

    VkPipelineDepthStencilStateCreateInfo depthStencil = {};
    depthStencil.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_DEPTH_STENCIL_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    depthStencil.depthTestEnable = VK_TRUE;
    depthStencil.depthWriteEnable = VK_TRUE;
    depthStencil.depthCompareOp = VK_COMPARE_OP_LESS;
    depthStencil.depthBoundsTestEnable = VK_FALSE;
    depthStencil.stencilTestEnable = VK_FALSE;

    VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo colorBlending = {};
    colorBlending.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_COLOR_BLEND_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    colorBlending.attachmentCount = 0;

    std::vector<VkDynamicState> dynamicStateEnables = {
        VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_VIEWPORT,
        VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_SCISSOR,
        VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_DEPTH_BIAS
    };

    VkPipelineDynamicStateCreateInfo dynamicState = {};
    dynamicState.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_DYNAMIC_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    dynamicState.dynamicStateCount = dynamicStateEnables.size();
    dynamicState.pDynamicStates = dynamicStateEnables.data();

    VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo pipelineInfo = {};
    pipelineInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineInfo.stageCount = 2;
    pipelineInfo.pStages = shaderStages;
    pipelineInfo.pVertexInputState = &vertexInputInfo;
    pipelineInfo.pInputAssemblyState = &inputAssembly;
    pipelineInfo.pViewportState = &viewportState;
    pipelineInfo.pRasterizationState = &rasterizer;
    pipelineInfo.pMultisampleState = &multisampling;
    pipelineInfo.pDepthStencilState = &depthStencil;
    pipelineInfo.pColorBlendState = &colorBlending;
    pipelineInfo.layout = shadowPipelineLayout;
    pipelineInfo.renderPass = shadowRenderPass;
    pipelineInfo.pDynamicState = &dynamicState;


    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(device, VK_NULL_HANDLE, 1, &pipelineInfo, nullptr, &shadowPipeline)); 


    vkDestroyShaderModule(device, shadowFragShaderModule, nullptr);
    vkDestroyShaderModule(device, shadowVertShaderModule, nullptr);

}

void VEngine::CreateShadowCommandBuffer()
{

    VkCommandBufferAllocateInfo allocInfo = {};
    allocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    allocInfo.commandPool = commandPool;
    allocInfo.level = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY;
    allocInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;

    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkAllocateCommandBuffers(device, &allocInfo, &shadowCommandbuffer));

    VkCommandBufferBeginInfo cmdBufInfo = {};
    cmdBufInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
    cmdBufInfo.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_SIMULTANEOUS_USE_BIT;

    VkClearValue clearValues[1];
    clearValues[0].color = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
    clearValues[0].depthStencil = { 1.0f, 0 };

    VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassBeginInfo = {};
    renderPassBeginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
    renderPassBeginInfo.renderPass = shadowRenderPass;
    renderPassBeginInfo.framebuffer = shadowFramebuffers;
    renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.offset.x = 0;
    renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.offset.y = 0;
    renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.extent.width = shadow_width;
    renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.extent.height = shadow_height;
    renderPassBeginInfo.clearValueCount = 1;
    renderPassBeginInfo.pClearValues = clearValues;

    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkBeginCommandBuffer(shadowCommandbuffer, &cmdBufInfo));

    VkViewport viewport = {};
    viewport.width = shadow_width;
    viewport.height = shadow_height;
    viewport.minDepth = 0;
    viewport.maxDepth = 1;

    vkCmdSetViewport(shadowCommandbuffer, 0, 1, &viewport);

    VkRect2D scissor = {};
    scissor.offset.x = 0;
    scissor.offset.y = 0;
    scissor.extent.width = shadow_width;
    scissor.extent.height = shadow_height;

    vkCmdSetScissor(shadowCommandbuffer, 0, 1, &scissor);

    // Set depth bias (aka "Polygon offset")
    // Required to avoid shadow mapping artefacts
    vkCmdSetDepthBias(
        shadowCommandbuffer,
        1.25f,
        0.0f,
        1.75f);

    vkCmdBeginRenderPass(shadowCommandbuffer, &renderPassBeginInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);

    vkCmdBindPipeline(shadowCommandbuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, shadowPipeline);
    vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(shadowCommandbuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, shadowPipelineLayout, 0, 1, &shadowDescriptorSet, 0, NULL);

    VkDeviceSize offsets[1] = { 0 };
    vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(shadowCommandbuffer, 0, 1, &shadowVertexBuffer, offsets);
    vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(shadowCommandbuffer, shadowIndexBuffer, 0, VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32);

    vkCmdDrawIndexed(shadowCommandbuffer, static_cast<uint32_t>(indices.size()), 1, 0, 0, 0);

    vkCmdEndRenderPass(shadowCommandbuffer);

    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkEndCommandBuffer(shadowCommandbuffer));

}

void VEngine::UpdateShadowUniformBuffer()
{
    void* uboData;
    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkMapMemory(device, shadowUniformBufferMemory, 0, sizeof(ShadowUBO), 0, &uboData));
    memcpy(uboData, &ubo.depthMVP, sizeof(ShadowUBO));
    vkUnmapMemory(device, shadowUniformBufferMemory);
}
```

I want use shadowCommandbuffer render a depth image for  implement shadow effect. I create shadow image, imageview, framebuffer, renderpass, vertex buffer, index buffer, uniform buffer, descriptor set, commandbuffer, almost everything I think need, but in frame buffer have not right depth image output. In renderdoc just only one commandBuffer submit that not shadowCommandBuffer. I have checked code many times, but I don't know where wrong. Hope you can help me. Thanks.

thanks!
i have been fixed commandBffer submit problem.
but

[i get frame buffer output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbpmG.png)

This is my depth format problem.i find it.thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please reduce your code to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), right now this is way too much code to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `VEngine::drawFrame` you create two `VkSubmitInfo` structures, which are initialised to 0 with `VkSubmitInfo ... = {}`.

For the `submitInfo` you set both `.commandBufferCount` to `1` and `.pCommandBuffers` to the command buffer you want to submit, but in `shadowSubmitInfo` you only set `.pCommandBuffers`, which leaves `.commandBufferCount` as the value `0` - meaning no command buffers are submitted.

If you set `shadowSubmitInfo.commandBufferCount` to `1` then it should work better (although I can't say if there are any other problems).

Comment: Thank you. I’m too careless! You solved my problem. Than you very much.

Comment: i get a strange depth image!